# Why object creation is not needed when we monkey patch Array or String class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching

What is the logic behind not creating an object to call methods when we monkey patch an Array/String class in Ruby?

E.g

```
class String
  def custom_reverse
    self.reverse.concat("anystring")
  end
end

"MohantySan".custom_reverse
 => "naSytnahoManystring"
```

AFAIK, custom_reverse is instance method for String class, Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with monkeypatching but with string literals. When you do

```
"MohantySan".custom_reverse
```

is like

```
String.new("MohantySan").custom_reverse
```

But strings are so of common usage that they have a convenient way to instantiate objects.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby classes are open, so you can add method to any class. Even more ruby class are object, that can create another objects. When you define methods like this, it accessible in all of this class instances

```
class Foo
  def foo(name)
    puts "foo #{name}"
  end
end
```